# Input link in1:v0 parameters (size XXX, SAR XXX) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (XXX, SAR 1:1)

Tags: ffmpeg

I've two files, a `mp4` and a `mp3` file. I want to add a `3` seconds intro screen with title `Welcome` and `black` background to the head of the video with the `mp3` as background. So here's what I wrote.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i input.mp4 \
    -i bgm.mp3 \
    -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s="1280"x"544":d=3.0 \
    -filter_complex \
        "[2:v]
  drawtext=
    fontsize=30
    :fontcolor=white
    :x=(w-text_w)/2
    :y=(h-text_h)/2
    :text='WELCOME'
[introVideo];

[1:a]
    atrim=0.0:3.0
[introAudio];

[introVideo][introAudio][0:v][0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -preset superfast output.mp4
```

but am getting below error when I try to execute the command

```
[Parsed_concat_3 @ 0x55c02756fa00] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1280x544, SAR 1299:1280) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x544, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_3 @ 0x55c02756fa00] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_3
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS: I am a beginner in video processing and `ffmpeg`.

Comment: See 2nd command in answer at duplicate link.

Comment: @Gyan: running concat with `unsafe` flag seems not recommended. Is it possible to set the aspect ratio of input video to `-f lavfi -i color...` ?

Comment: Insert `[0:v]setsar=1[0v];` before the concat filter, and use label `0v` in place of `0:v` in concat.

Comment: Oh my god, it worked. One more doubt @Gyan. What If I don't want to change `sar` of `input` but want to change `sar` of `[2:v]` to `sar` of  `0:v` ?

Comment: Then insert setsar for 2v after the final filter (geq).

Comment: @Gyan `setsar` with value `1` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105059/discussion-between-theapache64-and-gyan).

Comment: No, with the SAR value for 0:v - 1299:1280

Comment: I tried with `setsar=1299/1280`, but am getting same error. :( @Gyan

Comment: @Gyan Do you know why it's not working ?